# Pixel accurate OpenGL rendering using multisampled FBO and resolve FBO

Tags: opengl

I'm "forced" to do some offscreen rendering and compositing and am trying to get pixel accurate results with some simple examples.

If I render to a multi sampled FBO (containing a texture buffer) and then do a glBlitFramebuffer() to the default frame buffer with the same number of samples the result is 100% correct (so the texture is correct).

But if I resolve the texture first, by blitting to an intermediate single sampled FBO and then blit that result to the default (multi sampled) frame buffer the results are slightly off. Visible at the silhouette edges of the geometry. I'm not rendering the texture as fullscreen quad (yet). Just blits.

Would this be an error or is this unavoidable?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. I can't think of anything other than a mismatch between width/height that might cause that. Maybe try [resolving manually](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/173275-Alternative-to-glBlitFramebuffer()) and see if you get the same result?